# How can I take advantage of justify-content: space-between's automatic spacing with uneven number of elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a nicely defined grid system:

```
.col-3-grid {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-3-grid .grid-item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 32%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 32%;
    flex: 0 0 32%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
}
```

It looks good when there are 3 elements on a line:

[Elements look good when they're 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88ZVH.jpg)

But the moment an uneven number of items that are not first-row 2 or any other rows multiple or 3, this happens:

[Elements look bad when they're 5, 8 or so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O20Ee.jpg)

Between the 4th and 6th items, there's a gap. This is expected, but this approach is so elegant, I really don't wanna give it up for `justify-content: flex-start` because then I'd need to add paddings to each of my elements and they'd never align with others.

In short, I wanna keep `space-between` but make the items go in a line on each row.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible using `justify-content:space-between`. However you can use margin to every middle element i.e. 2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th so on...

```
.col-3-grid .grid-item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 2%;
}
```

No need to use `justify-content:space-between`

```css
.col-3-grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-3-grid .grid-item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 32%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 32%;
  flex: 0 0 32%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
  height: 30px;
  background: gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col-3-grid .grid-item:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3-grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but how about I generate an empty box that could just fill the space? Given I know in my back-end code my grid is on 3 columns, perhaps I can just generate an empty box at the end to fill it all?

Comment: @coolpasta if you can achieve this by just writing a single line css, why write code for the empty box...make no sense to me